# Where should be data stored? Session variables OR Hidden fields?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an web app that basically does booking stuffs in PHASE 1.
I have planned to complete booking in 4/5 steps. First, checking device is ready or not, second seeing allocation of device, third getting customer information, fourth payment information.

I just want to know about how the data is to be stored till the last page where we store all data in the database. Till then, how to move data from one page to another.

Which technique is best?
If there are any other techniques to store informations from page to page, Please I need to know for my project.
I also need to protect those information from being hacked.

I am using PHP and framework is Codeigniter

Comment: `<input type="hidden" />` fields can't persist data. When form is submitted they send data to server, if you don't persist it, it's gone for good. Session however is maintained across requests (unless configured otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Primarily opinion based*, but each has pros and cons.

Storing in $_SESSION:

- **Pro:** allows you to store *private* data that you don't necessarily want to fire back to the user, ie: either application-internal data, or the user's private data that should *not* be returned into the page, such as credit card details, passwords, and other personal information.
- **Con:** The session will expire after its configured timeout, and the user will lose their work.

Storing in hidden fields:

- Basically reverse the pros and cons for $_SESSION.
- IMHO, using hidden fields like this is a huge kludge.

The ideal way is to use a [custom session handler](http://php.net/session.customhandler) to store the session data in a way that it is not lost when the session expires.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a multipart form, I would store the information from each part in a MySQL database which would give the end user the ability to save and come back later since sessions will expire.

Comment: Sesion will not expire untill and unless a browser is closed. Isn't it?? Did you mean saving each page form in database??

Comment: It all depends on the expiry of the session.  In either event, storing in mySQL is fine for a small site, but doesn't scale well - put $_SESSION in memcache and flush memcached session data to mySQL infrequently to avoid bottlenecks.

Comment: Session expiration usually defaults to 1440 seconds or 24 minutes of inactivity, i.e. user goes AFK with page open. so if they fill out 3 of the 4 pages of info, if that is all stored in a $_SESSION var and then  their kids start fighting or whatever and they get pulled away for 30 minutes, that data goes poof unless the server has been configured otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sessions. Hidden fields can be modified and exposed to the user via Google Dev Tools or Firebug or any other tools. So it's best to use Sessions.

Comment: what would be the security means to protect those data across the server?